# Regex to extract a sub string from a string between colon ":" and ","

Tags: regex

I need to identify a sub string from any strings based on a regular expression.

For Example, take the following strings:

```
It sent a notice of delivery of goods: UserName1 (00215478),UserName2 (00258747)

Sent a notice of delivery of the goods: User is not found, UserName2 (00258747)

It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: UserName1 (00215478),UserName2 (00258747)

It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: User is not found, UserName2 (00258747)


I want to get following result:

UserName1 (00215478)

User is not found

UserName1 (00215478)

User is not found
```

I have a formula, but it displays the substring after the colon

```
MID([String],FIND([String],':',1)+1,LEN([String]))
```

Comment: In the last line of your question, you drop what appears to be a fragment of a SQL query (possibly SQL Server).  Could you update your question with the tool you are actually using, along with sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should give you the wanted string in the captured variable and the string with the preceding colon and appending comma as the whole matched string:

```
:([^,]*),
```

Explanation:
The square brackets starting with the hat character define which characters to exclude [see this lesson](https://regexone.com/lesson/excluding_characters). Here we want any character except the comma.

Then the star makes it any number of such characters (non-comma).

The parenthesis capture the string that matches the inside within the whole string that matches the regex.

And the string should begin with a colon and end with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:(.+),` and get the desired substring in the 1st capturing group, or you can lookahead (and behind):

```
(?<=:).+(?=,)
```

https://regex101.com/r/t06IfY/1

Answer (score 0):

To put my two cents in:

```
:\s*([^,]+)
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sIFvXn/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the regex `:\s*([^,]+)`

[image]